# "Continuous walk" or "Continuous walking"?

Tags: nouns

The full sentence is
"30 minutes of continuous *Walk*."
or 
"30 Minutes of Continuous *Walking*."

Thanks.

Comment: That is not a "full sentence" - there's no verb. FWIW, "walking" is correct.

Comment: @Chappo "30 minutes of continuous Walk." *is* a sentence.

Comment: Both will work. Why should we think only one of them must be grammatical?

Comment: A full sentence would be "I was tired after thirty minutes of continuous walking".

Answer (score 3):

'A walk' is an outing on foot, as in 'go for a walk', but the activity is 'walking' By the way, '30 minutes of walking' is a phrase, not a 'full sentence'.

Comment: "Oh!" (And the foregoing *is* a sentence, btw.)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, though.

Comment: "A walk of 30 minutes" makes sense, but not '30 minutes of walk". It needs to be '30 minutes [spent in the activity] of walking'.

Comment: Will "30 minutes of brisk walk" work for you?

Comment: I have to side with Kris about it being a sentence. I don't think that the modifier *full* changes anything in that respect (whereas *complete* probably would have). Consider the first three sentences of *Bleak House* by Dickens: *London. Michaelmas term lately over, and the Lord Chancellor sitting in Lincoln’s Inn Hall. Implacable November weather.* What *30 minutes of continuous walk.* is **not** is a **clause**.

Comment: *[time interval] of walk* may be less preferable than *[time interval] of walking*, but the former construction is well-attested, e.g [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=NuEJBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA54&dq=%22hours%20of%20walk%22&pg=PA54#v=onepage&q=%22hours%20of%20walk%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=T1Q1AwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT49&dq=%22days%20of%20walk%22&pg=PT49#v=onepage&q=%22days%20of%20walk%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=QUQWAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22days%20of%20walk%22&pg=PA42#v=onepage&q=%22days%20of%20walk%22&f=false),

Comment: [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=IyhSDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT32&dq=%22days%20of%20walk%22&pg=PT32#v=onepage&q=%22days%20of%20walk%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=u1GNNPDy9-IC&lpg=PA81&dq=%22seconds%20of%20walk%22&pg=PA81#v=onepage&q=%22seconds%20of%20walk%22&f=false), [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=0kIWPIoakWUC&lpg=PA22&dq=%22minutes%20of%20walk%22&pg=PA22#v=onepage&q=%22minutes%20of%20walk%22&f=false), and [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=e4R5CwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA162&dq=%22seconds%20of%20walk%22&pg=PA162#v=onepage&q=%22seconds%20of%20walk%22&f=false).

Comment: Moreover, to my ear at least, the construction with *walk* becomes even more acceptable if preceded by a modifier such as *continuous, brisk,* etc.

Answer (score -2):

Both of these are acceptable, though [1b] would arguably be a much more common choice:

[1]  a.  *Thirty minutes of continuous **walk.***
       b.  *Thirty minutes of continuous **walking.***

(According to many style manuals, and in particular the *Chicago Manual of Style,* numbers that begin a sentence must always be spelled out. That's why I changed *30* to *Thirty.* Also, there is no reason for any other words to be capitalized.)

I partially agree with [Kate Bunting's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/467467/155553) that *walking* sounds better. But I can't go so far as to claim that [1a] is not acceptable. The construction *[time interval] of walk* is pretty well attested in published literature. Here are some examples:

1. *A pretty lad like you should get to Cramond (which is near in by Edinburgh)
 
    in **two days of walk.*** [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=RwEaBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA4&dq=%22in%20two%20days%20of%20walk%22&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q=%22in%20two%20days%20of%20walk%22&f=false)
2. *Weston, **6 days of walk*** [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=QUQWAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22days%20of%20walk%22&pg=PA42#v=onepage&q=%22days%20of%20walk%22&f=false)
3. ***4 days of walk*** [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=IyhSDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT32&dq=%22days%20of%20walk%22&pg=PT32#v=onepage&q=%22days%20of%20walk%22&f=false)
4. ***11 seconds of walk*** per each worker [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=u1GNNPDy9-IC&lpg=PA81&dq=%22seconds%20of%20walk%22&pg=PA81#v=onepage&q=%22seconds%20of%20walk%22&f=false)
5. ***20-30 minutes of walk***/jog [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=0kIWPIoakWUC&lpg=PA22&dq=%22minutes%20of%20walk%22&pg=PA22#v=onepage&q=%22minutes%20of%20walk%22&f=false)
6. *Most runners will have their most significant improvement in fatigue during the first 10-15
 
    seconds of the walk break so that the **20 seconds of walk** in the R10sec/W20sec example
 
    can produce rather fast times overall.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=e4R5CwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA162&dq=%2220%20seconds%20of%20walk%20in%20the%22&pg=PA162#v=onepage&q=%2220%20seconds%20of%20walk%20in%20the%22&f=false)

And the *walking* construction is certainly well attested; indeed, my impression is that it is much more common than the construction with *walk*:

1. ***90 seconds of walking*** [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=UaLSBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA125&dq=%22seconds%20of%20walking%22&pg=PA125#v=onepage&q=%22seconds%20of%20walking%22&f=false)
2. *Alternate ten seconds of running with **20 seconds of walking.*** [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=FFxXDgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT150&dq=%22seconds%20of%20walking%22&pg=PT150#v=onepage&q=%22seconds%20of%20walking%22&f=false)
3. *While most people are capable of at least **thirty minutes of walking,** perhaps forty-five
 
    minutes is a good starting point.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=_ERfBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA257&dq=%22minutes%20of%20walking%22&pg=PA257#v=onepage&q=%22minutes%20of%20walking%22&f=false)
4. *End with **5 minutes of walking,** gradually decreasing the pace to a comfortable walk.*
 
    [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=C27XBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1068&dq=%22minutes%20of%20walking%22&pg=PA1068#v=onepage&q=%22minutes%20of%20walking%22&f=false)
5. *After **three hours of walking,** I realized something horrible.* [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ujTmLYMQpQgC&lpg=PA85&dq=%22hours%20of%20walking%22&pg=PA85#v=onepage&q=%22hours%20of%20walking%22&f=false)

**The construction *[time interval] of [something]* in general: the plain noun or the *-ing* form?**

I should say that, in general, it seems to me that is not predictable whether the gerund-participial form (*-ing*) or the plain noun form will be better in the construction  *[time interval] of [something]*. On the one hand, to my ear at least, [2a] sounds fine, whereas [2b] sounds much less likely:

[2]  a.  *It takes three hours of **work.***
       b.  *<sup>?</sup>It takes three hours of **working.***

On the other hand, [3b] sounds to me perfectly natural, while [3a] sounds quite unnatural:

[3]  a.  *<sup>?</sup>It is thirty minutes of **climb.***
       b.  *It is thirty minutes of **climbing.***

(However, even the construction in [3a] is attested in published literature, see [here](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22hours+of+climb%22) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&tbm=bks&ei=a--8W9PkBKnp_Qbd65W4Bg&q=%22minutes+of+climb%22&oq=%22minutes+of+climb%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...96283.97774.0.98024.8.8.0.0.0.0.213.618.3j1j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.0.0....0.vdctZbcSFPk).)

Moreover, acceptability seems to be affected by the presence or absence of modifiers. For example, to my ear at least, *thirty minutes of **working hard*** sounds much more acceptable than *thirty minutes of **working**.* And *Two hours of **steep climb*** sounds to me better than *Two hours of **climb.***

**Are [1a] and [1b] *full sentences*?**

A tangential issue concerns whether [1a] and [1b] are **full sentences.** I will argue that they are indeed *full* sentences, but that they are not *complete* sentences.

Note that while the definition of a (finite) **clause** is quite clear in English grammar, things are far murkier as far as the definition of a *sentence*. A finite clause—[a unit consisting of a subject plus a finite verb and any complements and modifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause)— is definitely a sentence, provided it begins with a capital letter and ends with a termination mark (i.e. a period, a question mark, or an exclamation mark). But must a sentence be a finite clause (or a coordination of finite clauses)? Arguably not. Consider the beginning of Dickens's *Bleak House*:

> London. Michaelmas term lately over, and the Lord Chancellor sitting in Lincoln’s Inn Hall. Implacable November weather.

Arguably, Dickens meant these to be three sentences. But there is not a single finite clause among them.

Wikipedia has a serviceable definition of a sentence ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_(linguistics))): a set of words that in principle, at least in its context, tells a complete thought; it may be a simple phrase, but it conveys enough meaning to imply a clause. And as far as functional grammar, all that's required of a finite sequence of words to constitute a sentence is, roughly, that it begins with a capital letter and end with a period, a question mark, or an exclamation mark [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=JM3KAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA6&dq=%22the%20sentence%20(beginning%20with%20a%20capital%20letter%20and%20ending%20with%20a%20full%20stop)%2C%22&pg=PA6#v=onepage&q=%22the%20sentence%20(beginning%20with%20a%20capital%20letter%20and%20ending%20with%20a%20full%20stop),%22&f=false).

When we say that [1a] and [1b] are ***full*** sentences, I take that to mean that we haven't omitted anything. They really begin with *Thirty*, capitalized, and end with *walk/walking* and a period. In particular, I take that to mean that they have not been extracted from larger sentences such as *All it takes is thirty minutes of continuous walking.*

On the other hand, I take [1a] and [1b] to not be ***complete*** sentences. My impression is that when we qualify *sentence* by *complete*, we really do mean that the sentence is either a finite clause or a coordination of finite clauses. For example, in the article [*It's totally okay to write incomplete sentences,*](http://theweek.com/articles/465459/totally-okay-write-incomplete-sentences) the adjective *incomplete* clearly refers to the fact that the sentences considered there do not have both a subject and a verb (and aren't coordinations of sentences that do).

Comment: @HaniDahman Sure, no problem...!