# Is "Canned meats, rated." a valid and correct English sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

Canned meats, rated.
Pencils, handled.
Popes, interviewed.

In other words, is the construction [Subject], [past tense verb] a valid sentence.

If so, does this construction, or the clause after the comma have an actual name?

Comment: There is no name because it is not a valid English sentence. You might see this used in dialogue, but dialogue is not indicative of English grammar necessarily.

Comment: These are items in a briefly summarised list. They are not sentences.

Comment: I see you objected to a downvote. Probably someone thought you needed a little more research before asking if a sentence without a verb is a good example of normal English.

Comment: Is “rated” not a past-tense verb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paraphrasing a bit what the others have said in the comments, these are not what we would call **complete** English sentences. But they are arguably **full** sentences, and there are circumstances when native speakers would accept them as such, e.g. in certain types of speech and prose.

**Discussion**

Note that while the definition of a (finite) **clause** is quite clear in English grammar, things are far murkier as far as the definition of a *sentence*. A finite clause—[a unit consisting of a subject plus a finite verb and any complements and modifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause)— is definitely a sentence, provided it begins with a capital letter and ends with a termination mark (i.e. a period, a question mark, or an exclamation mark). But must a sentence be a finite clause (or a coordination of finite clauses)? Arguably not. Consider the beginning of Dickens's *Bleak House*:

> London. Michaelmas term lately over, and the Lord Chancellor sitting in Lincoln’s Inn Hall. Implacable November weather.

Arguably, Dickens meant these to be three sentences. But there is not a single finite clause among them.

Wikipedia has a serviceable definition of a sentence ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_(linguistics))): a set of words that in principle, at least in its context, tells a complete thought; it may be a simple phrase, but it conveys enough meaning to imply a clause. And as far as functional grammar, all that's required of a finite sequence of words to constitute a sentence is, roughly, that it begins with a capital letter and end with a period, a question mark, or an exclamation mark [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=JM3KAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA6&dq=%22the%20sentence%20(beginning%20with%20a%20capital%20letter%20and%20ending%20with%20a%20full%20stop)%2C%22&pg=PA6#v=onepage&q=%22the%20sentence%20(beginning%20with%20a%20capital%20letter%20and%20ending%20with%20a%20full%20stop),%22&f=false).

When I say that your examples are ***full** sentences*, I mean that we haven't omitted anything. They really begin with a capitalized word and end with a period. In particular, I mean that they have not been extracted from larger sentences (though clearly there are some larger sentences to which they are intimately related, e.g. *Pencils have been handled*).

On the other hand, your examples are not ***complete** sentences.* My impression is that when we qualify *sentence* by *complete*, we really do mean that the sentence is either a finite clause or a coordination of finite clauses. For example, in the article [*It's totally okay to write incomplete sentences,*](http://theweek.com/articles/465459/totally-okay-write-incomplete-sentences) the adjective *incomplete* clearly refers to the fact that the sentences considered there do not have both a subject and a verb (and aren't coordinations of sentences that do).

(I've borrowed from [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/467552/155553) of mine.)

Comment: Wow.  Thank you so much for explaining so completely.  I genuinely learned something.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: The UK Guardian has [a column](https://www.theguardian.com/books/series/digestedread) called 'The Digested Read" in which books are reviewed by condensing them into a single page in the style of the book itself. The whole thing is then sarcastically summed up in a single final sentence titled “The digested read ... digested”. [Example](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2003/jun/30/harrypotter.theeditorpressreview) (Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix by JK Rowling) "The digested read ... digested:  Kevin Potter and the Goose that laid the Golden Egg".

Comment: Saying that a sentence is 'a set of words that . . . tells a complete thought' is of limited help here, because it raises the question of what distinguishes a complete thought from an incomplete one, and that is not a straightforward matter.